# Class-Path in manifest gets disordered

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I am creating a jar file with multiple jars referred in Class-Path manifest.mf.

After the jar is created I could see the Class-Path entry values are jumbled up. Please suggest how I can fix it?

I entered like:

```
lib\axis.jar
 lib\axis-ant.jar
```

In the jar file it wil become something like:

```
lib\axis.j
arlib\axis-ant.jar
```

Comment: What  tool/IDE you are using ? The jar file works ? How do you view the MF in the jar ?

Comment: I am using jar command, using securezip to view the Manifest.MF inside the created jar.

Comment: Does last line end with a new line? Take a look a this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.

Comment: Yes it is ending with a newline.

`lib\xercesImpl.jar lib\xmlParserAPIs.jar 

 `

Comment: As @PeterMmm asked, Jar works or does it complain about such libraries? If it doesn't work, try put all libraries in one line, separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your JAR contains a section similar to this:

```
Classpath: lib\axis.jar
 lib\axis-ant.jar
```

This is a single value split onto multiple lines (the first line, and a continuation line). It is exactly equivalent to:

```
Classpath: lib\axis.jarlib\axis-ant.jar
```

The newline and space that indicates a continuation line is *not* part of the value.

The value needs to include a space between the two filenames. For example (still using a continuation; note the extra space):

```
Classpath: lib\axis.jar
  lib\axis-ant.jar
```

Also, note that the JAR tool is within its rights to adjust how lines are split, since this doesn't affect how the value is interpreted. This:

```
Classpath: lib\axis.j
 arlib\axis-ant.jar
```

is still equivalent to:

```
Classpath: lib\axis.jarlib\axis-ant.jar
```

so the JAR tool is not doing anything wrong by making that change.